# avoiding blank and duplicate entries submitted to sql

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic

I'm struggling with the logic of this code. I think the blank entries occur when the back button is used. It is for a questionnaire system for disabled learners where only 1 question is asked per page and the results are submitted individually for each question. There is a separate table for determining if the survey has been fully completed (I track a uniqueID using GET) and results only come through from those that are fully completed.

I have attempted using UPDATE response / comment where quesitonID and Unique ID exists, but this seem to create more problems. For the sake of clarity and to allow some freedom in ideas, I've whittled the code down to the bare minimum. Many thanks.

EDIT: 'response' is a radio button entry and 'comment' is text input. 'UniqueID', 'surveyID', 'QID' & 'type' are determined in the URL and captured using GET.

```
mysql_query("

INSERT INTO answers (uniqueID, surveyID, QID, type, response, comment) 
SELECT '$U', '$S','$Q', '$t', '$response', '$comments' 

") 
or die(mysql_error());  


if (isset($_GET['start']))   {

mysql_query("

INSERT INTO complete (uniqueID, surveyID) 
VALUES('$U', '$S') 

") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

}     

if (isset($_GET['finished']))   { 

mysql_query("

UPDATE complete 
SET timestamp = NOW() 
WHERE uniqueID='$U' 

") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

Comment: Where is the code that validates input? How would you want to avoid duplicates and empty values when you code does not implement this?

Comment: It's the validation that I'm confused over. What method do you think is best to work with this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not do any validation, it just `die`s when there's an error.
This will not do in production code.

As far as validation goes you have 2 options:

A - Check the input in php and disallow any illegal values.
B - Use SQL constraints and monitor the output there.
Or a combination of the two.

The problem with option **B** is that you'll just get an error back from MySQL that you'll have to handle in php.
For that reason I'd go for option A.

**First step: escape your input**
The best way to do this is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).
If you use the `mysql_` lib you'll have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on each and every input to escape it and quote your `$vars`; like so:

```
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['param1']);
examplequery = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 = '$a' ";
```

For integer values you can cast the variable to an integer, and then inject it without quotes.

```
$a = intval($_GET['param1']);
$b = intval($_GET['param2']);
if $a > $b { list($a,$b) = array($b,$a); }  //Exchange the two vars if needed.
examplequery = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 BETWEEN $a AND $b";
```

**Validating your data**
Here again you have two options, you can hardcode the validation into php, or use SQL to check the input.
I like the second approach, because it allows you to put all info in valid input into the database.

**Validating your data using a validation table**
  One option is to create a table like so:

```
table Checks (
  fieldname varchar(50) not null,
  tablename varchar(50) not null,
  fieldtype enum('int','varchar','enum','decimal'.....) not null,
  min_value double default -1000000;
  max_value double default 1000000;
  validation_query varchar(1000) default null, 
  primary key (tablename, fieldname)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now you can check a param like so (using PDO):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fieldtype, min_value, max_value, validation_query
                       FROM checks WHERE fieldname = ? AND tablename = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('field1', 'table1'));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
switch ($result['type']) {
  case 'int':
    $allOK = isnumeric($inputvalue_to_check); 
    $allOK = $allOK AND ($intval($inputvalue_to_check) >= $result['min_value']
                     AND $intval($inputvalue_to_check) <= $result['max_value']);
    if is_null($result['validation_query']) {
      $sql = $result['validation_query'];
      $check = $dbh-?prepare($sql);
      $check_result = $check->execute(array($inputvalue_to_check));
      $check_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if is_null($check_result['result']) { //value is not OK}
    break;
  case .......
```

**Validating in php**
If you know your data and it's not subject to change, you can do the validation using `if` and `switch` statements.
This code looks a lot like the above code, except that it does not fetch data from the database, the logic is hardcoded instead or is stored in php datastructures.

Comment: Thank you so much for this level of detail and effort. Will really help me understand validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask how to make mysql complain when duplicate or empty values are inserted the answer is:

- UNIQUE constraint on (uniqueID, surveyID, QID) for avoiding duplicates
- NOT NULL constraint for avoiding blank values

to read on constraints loook into [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

But I would also check in PHP if the provided values are present and properly formatted. Not mentioning that `SELECT '$U', '$S','$Q', '$t', '$response', '$comments'` way of writing queries is very dangerous since allows code injections of different kinds.